# Ruby on Rails: gem or plugin for definitions on a medical form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a website with a rather lengthy medical questionnaire. The users/patients need to be able to hover or click on a medical term and see the definition.

What are ways to accomplish this in RoR? There are similar plugins for WordPress, but I haven't found any in Rails.

My idea is have a Term model, that has attributes "word" and a "definition". Then in my layouts, I have to somehow scan the page and output the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches.  I use jquery-tooltip.  I'm in the same boat, instead of medical forms in my case it's insurance forms.

I checked out a few different approaches.  I really like the tooltip feature coming soon to jquery-ui 1.9.  Until it's officially released, I'm using jquery-tooltip.

They both work the same,  give an element a title:

```
<div id='q12', title='This is number 12'>
   What is this?
</div>
```

Then

```
$('#q12').tooltip
```

If the only reason you ever give your elements a Title is to create a tooltip,  then you can just use something like:

```
    $("[title]").tooltip({ position: "center left", predelay:500 });
```

Then every element with a title defined will show your stylized tooltip when the element is hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Twitter's  [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework.

- [Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)
  These can be customized with images and any other content that you need.
- [Tooltips](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)
  Mainly for small snippets of text.
  `<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Medical Term: This term means this..">Medical Term</a>`
- [Popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)
  Can contain more information then tooltips, but not as versatile as a Modal.

You can find more information on using it in Rails 3.0/3.2 [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-custom_css).